# How to draw symbol (Right or Wrong ) on Image in java?

Tags: java, draw, symbols

I draw `Image` in `JPanel` using `Paint` method if it. after that, I draw 'Y' and 'N' as string on the image. But instead of 'Y' and 'N' , I want to draw symbol for Right or Wrong (like for wrong is 'X'). So how can I draw that type of symbol on image in java?

Comment: "Wright" is spelled rong :-) I think you'll find the word is "right".

Comment: @paxdiablo If I were you, I would have fixed his spelling instead of commenting

Comment: @Adel, if you were me, you would have done exactly what _I_ did. Otherwise you wouldn't be me :-) In any case, that was to be my next step but you beat me to it. Strangely enough, if I were you, I would have done exactly what you suggested :-)

Comment: hey, whatever happened to teaching a man to fish?

Comment: @paxdiablo There goes the paradoxe :P

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is multi-layering which in Java is a `JLayeredPane` and here's a tutorial:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html

Another way would be to draw an Overlay image and here's a tutorial too:

http://sanjaal.com/java/482/java-graphics-2d/java-how-to-overlay-one-image-over-another-using-graphics2d-tutorial/